# KDE apps stopped loading citing missing libQtSvg

Tags: kde, dependencies, konsole

Yesterday (and in the preceding months), I could use Konsole completely fine. I haven't intentionally changed anything since then. However, today it won't load:

```
[11:06]~$ konsole
konsole: error while loading shared libraries: libQtSvg.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[11:06]~$ locate libQtSvg.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtSvg.so.4.8.6
```

I tried 'okular' too. I don't really use any other KDE apps, but I imagine that this applies to all of them. It looks like the library is present, but is not being found. Any ideas what could cause this, or more importantly how to fix it?

It's linking fine against things in the same directory:

```
[11:18]~$ ldd `which konsole`
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff89dfe000)
        libkdeinit4_konsole.so => /usr/lib/kde4/libkdeinit/libkdeinit4_konsole.so (0x00007f6a91580000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6a91195000)
        libkonsoleprivate.so => /usr/lib/libkonsoleprivate.so (0x00007f6a90e8f000)
        libknotifyconfig.so.4 => /usr/lib/libknotifyconfig.so.4 (0x00007f6a90c7d000)
        libkio.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkio.so.5 (0x00007f6a907d4000)
        libkdeui.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5 (0x00007f6a9018c000)
        libkdecore.so.5 => /usr/lib/libkdecore.so.5 (0x00007f6a8fccb000)
        libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0x00007f6a8f7e6000)
        libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0x00007f6a8eb32000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f6a8e82e000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6a917a5000)
        libkpty.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkpty.so.4 (0x00007f6a8e624000)
        libkonq.so.5abi1 => /usr/lib/libkonq.so.5abi1 (0x00007f6a8e3ec000)
        libQtNetwork.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtNetwork.so.4 (0x00007f6a8e0a4000)
        libQtDBus.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtDBus.so.4 (0x00007f6a8de29000)
        libphonon.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libphonon.so.4 (0x00007f6a8dbb0000)
        libnepomuk.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomuk.so.4 (0x00007f6a8d8e5000)
        libQtXml.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtXml.so.4 (0x00007f6a8d6a0000)
        libQtSvg.so.4 => not found
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f6a8d36a000)
        libstreamanalyzer.so.0 => /usr/lib/libstreamanalyzer.so.0 (0x00007f6a8d0ec000)
        libsolid.so.4 => /usr/lib/libsolid.so.4 (0x00007f6a8cdeb000)
        libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f6a8cbe3000)
        libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f6a8c9de000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f6a8c7d3000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6a8c4cd000)
        libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007f6a8c2c5000)
        libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007f6a8c0a8000)
        libattica.so.0.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattica.so.0.4 (0x00007f6a8bdc5000)
        libQtSvg.so.4 => not found
        libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbusmenu-qt.so.2 (0x00007f6a8bb92000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f6a8b98c000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f6a8b773000)
        libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f6a8b562000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f6a8b340000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6a8b122000)
        libdlrestrictions.so.1 => /usr/lib/libdlrestrictions.so.1 (0x00007f6a8af1c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f6a8ad06000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6a8ab02000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6a8a7f9000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f6a8a5f1000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f6a8a3b5000)
        libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0x00007f6a8a19c000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f6a89f76000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f6a89cd3000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f6a89a81000)
        libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f6a89871000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f6a8965f000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f6a8945b000)
        libutempter.so.0 => /usr/lib/libutempter.so.0 (0x00007f6a89258000)
        libkparts.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkparts.so.4 (0x00007f6a89004000)
        libkfile.so.4 => /usr/lib/libkfile.so.4 (0x00007f6a88d5e000)
        libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f6a88b19000)
        libpulse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 (0x00007f6a888cf000)
        libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0 (0x00007f6a886ca000)
        libsoprano.so.4 => /usr/lib/libsoprano.so.4 (0x00007f6a883e1000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f6a881c2000)
        libstreams.so.0 => /usr/lib/libstreams.so.0 (0x00007f6a87f8b000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f6a87c24000)
        libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f6a87a13000)
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f6a8780e000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f6a875cf000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f6a873a5000)
        libXt.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXt.so.6 (0x00007f6a8713f000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f6a86f3a000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f6a86d32000)
        libnepomukutils.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomukutils.so.4 (0x00007f6a86af7000)
        libjson-c.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.2 (0x00007f6a868ec000)
        libpulsecommon-4.0.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-4.0.so (0x00007f6a86684000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f6a8647e000)
        libcgmanager.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0 (0x00007f6a86262000)
        libnih.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1 (0x00007f6a8604a000)
        libnih-dbus.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1 (0x00007f6a85e40000)
        libnepomukquery.so.4 => /usr/lib/libnepomukquery.so.4 (0x00007f6a85bf9000)
        libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007f6a859ef000)
        libsndfile.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 (0x00007f6a85786000)
        libasyncns.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 (0x00007f6a85580000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f6a85365000)
        libFLAC.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 (0x00007f6a85134000)
        libvorbisenc.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 (0x00007f6a84c65000)
        libvorbis.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0 (0x00007f6a84a37000)
        libogg.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0 (0x00007f6a8482e000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f6a84613000)
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I've fixed this. A bunch of libQt libraries had got screwed up. No idea what caused it.

Resolved with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libqt4-svg libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-test
```